# Multi-Threading. MyLock.acquire() , Where the lock should be placed?

Tags: python, multithreading

Greeting ..

In following code where **lock** should be acquired before or after try? Which is efficient? The code is working fine, however, I would like to make sure my code is perfectly locking the thread.

```
def DoThis(name, repeat):
    global x, MyLock
    MyLock.acquire()
    try:
        print ("Thread ",name, "Has Acquired the LOCK")
        while repeat > 0:
            x = x * 2
            print (" X = ", x)
            repeat -= 1
    except:
        raise #raise exception
    finally:
        MyLock.release()
        print("Thread ", name, "Has Released the LOCK")

def DoAfter(name, repeat):
    global x, MyLock
    MyLock.acquire()
    try:
        print ("Thread ",name, "Has Acquired the LOCK")
        while repeat > 0:
            x = x + 1
            print (" X = ", x)
            repeat -= 1
    except:
        raise #raise exception
    finally:
        MyLock.release()
        print("Thread ", name, "Has Released the LOCK")

def main():
    print("Hello World")
    global x, MyLock
    x = 2
    MyLock = threading.Lock()
    # My_Thread = threading.Thread(target = MyFunc)
    # We can modify the previous line by adding a thread name
    My_Thread_1 = threading.Thread(target = DoThis, args = ('My Thread 1',20))
    My_Thread_1.start()
    My_Thread_2 = threading.Thread(target = DoAfter, args = ('My Thread 2', 20))
    My_Thread_2.start()
    print ("Final X = ", x )
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know the purpose of `locks`. In your case if you want to handle lock exceptions such as `could not obtain lock` then you can use lock inside try block and can handle it.

I'm suggesting this because in important jobs such as `db transactions` it is better to use locks inside try block as you can handle lock exceptions by reverting the db transactions. So it is better to handle locks in `try` block.